# How to use TLD name only for internal network

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, dynamic-dns

I found a lot of different variations of these questions, but none of similar to something I would like to do.

I had a *dnsmasq* running with pointing to my local (internal server). My router was checking dnsmasq first for domain name mapping and it was all fine.

I wonder if I can avoid running dnsmasq service internally and move domain name resolution to a public domain service **without** exposing my services publically?

Let's say I have a domain name registered with google something.xyz and server local address is 192.168.178.33, this service has few things running on different ports like service1 on port 9001 and service2 on port 9001.

I would like all my internal traffic to resolve these services by domain name and keep them available only internally.

```
          www.something.xyz -> 192.168.178.33:9001 -> service1
somesubdomain.something.xyz -> 192.168.178.33:9002 -> service2
```

Comment: A/AAAA records do not point at ports. Only SRV records do, but they are not widely used.

Comment: yes! that is right. My first point is to get the domain name pointing to the correct ip and then make the correct routing to ports.

At the moment I do get correct response from nslookup when:
`
$ nslookup something.xyz 8.8.8.8

Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   something.xyz 
Address: 192.168.178.33
`

But not when I call without 8.8.8.8:
`
   $ nslookup something.xyz 
   Server:         127.0.0.53
   Address:        127.0.0.53#53

   Non-authoritative answer:
   *** Can't find something.xyz : No answer
`

Comment: For a public service you'd likely need to own the corresponding tld. What you deliver might be limited by their terms of service. There's nothing really stopping you from resolving public DNS entries to private IPs. Whenever your servers respond depends on your network configuration. Though it can be a good idea to keep this information local rather than on public servers.

Answer (score 1):

:tada:

I found a problem I was facing. When I was on vpn *nslookup* was finding my internal ip address fine, while when I was on internal wifi it wasn't.
After some research, I found that there is protection from resolving internal network ips from public dns servers. Technically speaking my router was protecting me from dns rebinding attacks.

I had to whitelist the domain name in the router configuration and it seem to work fine now. For more information about this issue and [router config can be found here.](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7360-int/663_No-DNS-resolution-of-private-IP-addresses/)

Thanks to @Seth and @Daniel B for confirming that there should be no issue with resolving private ips with the public domain names.